# How to position two objects together in the bottom of a wellPanel in shiny?

Tags: r, layout, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to place the text inside p() function and the Download button in the bottom of this wellPanel, but cannot do so. What should I do here?

Using this div command allowed me to place one of them at the bottom, but can't do both without them kind of overlaping each other.

```
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "npx Chart")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar({
  sidebarMenu(id = "menu",
              menuItem("Phase I", tabName = "ph1", icon = icon("vial"), startExpanded = FALSE,
                       menuSubItem("Data", tabName = "yourdata", icon = icon("file-excel")))
  )
})

body <- dashboardBody({
  
  tabItems(
    
    tabItem(tabName = "yourdata",
            fluidPage(
              fluidRow(
                column(4,
                       wellPanel(div(style = "height:800px; position:relative;",
                                     selectInput(inputId = "dataset", "Choose a Control Chart:",
                                                 choices = c("np Control Chart")),
                                     
                                     fileInput(inputId = "Ph1Data", "Choose Phase I data (Excel file only)",
                                               accept = c(".xlsx")),
                                     
                                     sliderInput(inputId = "chooseARL0",
                                                 label = "Choose a Phase II In-Control Average run Lenght (ARL0)",
                                                 min = 100,
                                                 max = 1000,
                                                 value = 370),
                                     
                                     p("If you do not have a process to monitor but want to know how the app works, you can 
                                  download a file to test here",
                                       style = "font-size: 12pt; position: absolute; bottom: 0;left: 0;", align = "justify"),        
                                     downloadButton("botao", "Download")
                       ))),
                column(8,
                       (DT::dataTableOutput("table_data"))
                )
              )))
  )
  
})
```

Comment: Does a combination of `fluidRow()` and `column()` give you what you want?  If not, why not?

Comment: So apparently I can do it in a sidebarLayout placing a wellPanel inside the sidebarPanel and using the style command. With fluidRow() and column() I don't know how I would send the content to the bottom, it would probably just go right below the first column right?

Comment: Why don't you try it and report back?  We can't since you haven't given us a MWE.  And please pay attention to the *minimal* part of MWE.

Comment: Sorry, what is a MWE? I will definitely give it a try and report back when I found the best solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: MWE: Minimal Working Example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Group the `p` tag and the `downloadButton` in a `div`, and set the positioning style to this `div`:

```
          div(
            style = "position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;",
            p("If you do not have a process to monitor but want to know how the app works, you can
                              download a file to test here",
              style = "font-size: 12pt;", align = "justify"
            ),
            downloadButton("botao", "Download")
          )
```